# How to "map" an array to a single new object?

Tags: arrays, scala, dictionary, reduce

I have an Array[Float] and I'd like to use the elements of that array to initialize a new object.

In a classic, imperative way, I could of course do simply do:

```
val array: Array[Float] = ...
val rect: Rect = new Rect(Point(array(0), array(1), Size(array(2), array(3))
```

Is there a way to do it in a more functional way using some type of a "map"? Something like this:

```
array => new Rect(Point(_(0), _(1)), Size(_(2), _(3)))
```

I'm trying to parse a CSV file:

```
string.split("\n") map {
  line => line.split(".") map { 
    value => value.trim.toDouble
  } => new Rect(Point(_(0), _(1)), Size(_(2), _(3))) // something like this?
}
```

Comment: What is your definition of functional? Why do you think that your implementation is not functional?

Answer (score 2):

Is the size of the array fixed?  You could use pattern matching:

```
.map { case Array(x, y, w, h) => new Rect(Point(x, y), Size(w, h)) }
```

Example:

```
scala> "1,2,3,4\n5,6,7,8".split("\n").map(_.split(",")).map { case Array(x,y,w,h) => (x,y,w,h) }
res3: Array[(String, String, String, String)] = Array((1,2,3,4), (5,6,7,8))
```

Comment: Did you mean match? I get a compile error with map. Otherwise I think this may be the closest to what I was hoping for.

Comment: You can use this syntax to define a PartialFunction literal inline.  But you're right I have missed that the thing you map over is not something like `Option[Array[Int]]`. I have added an example using `map { case `, but using `match` is perfectly fine as well

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about being functional, but repeating variable name 4 times like `array(n)` can arguably be improved by destructuring:

```
val Array(x, y, w, h) = "1,2,3,4".split(",").map(_.trim.toDouble)
new Rect(Point(x, y), Size(w, h))
```

(similar to the Markus1189 answer, only it doesn't have to be an anonymous function)

I would say it's more about readability than being functional

Answer (score 1):

The above suggestion is good but error prone, it uses an extractor, eg the `unnapply` on Array added by Scala. The problem I see is getting a `MatchError` if the CSV file is corrupted.

This approach would simply skip the lines in the file which don't match the criteria, but what if you just want to take the first 4 lines?

```
csv.lines.map {
  case Array(x, y, w, h) => Some(new Rect(Point(x, y), Size(w, h)))
  case _ => None
} flatten
```

If you want to simply extract the first four variables, even if the CSV line has more than 4 elements, you can use the a slightly different syntax, which is a way of saying the line should have "at least 4 elements".

```
csv.lines.map {
   case Array(x, y, w, h, _*) => Some(new Rect(Point(x, y), Size(w, h)))
   case _ => None
} flatten
```

You can even obtain a reference to the "rest of the elements" with the `tail @ _*` syntax. If you would like to have more fine grained control over the parsing and have some nice error reporting:

```
val detailed: Array[Try[Rect]] = csv.lines.map {
  case Array(x, y, w, h, tail @ _: *) => {
    Success(new Rect(Point(x, y), Size(w, h)))
  }
  case arr @ _ => Failure(s"Entry had ${arr.size} elements, expected at least 4. ${arr.mkString(",")}")
}
```

For even better flow control, I'd separate the `map` logic in something like `parseRow(input: Array[String]): Try[Rect]`.

```
def parseRow(input: Array[String]): Try[Rect] = input match {
  case Array(x, y, w, h, tail @ _: *) => {
    Success(new Rect(Point(x, y), Size(w, h)))
  }
  case arr @ _ => Failure(s"Entry had ${arr.size} elements, expected at least 4. ${arr.mkString(",")}")
}
```

You could even think about more fine-grained handling of any conversions you will have to perform, to go from instance from a string input to a `Double` or whatever math type is needed for `Rect`.

Here's a full setup that I would use:

```
  case class Point(x: Double, y: Double)
  case class Size(x: Double, y: Double)
  class Rect(val p: Point, val s: Size)

  def parseDouble(input: String): Try[Double] = Try(input.toDouble)

  def parseRow(input: Array[String]): Try[Rect] = input match {
    case Array(x, y, w, h, tail @ _*) => {
      for {
        pointX <- parseDouble(x)
        pointY <- parseDouble(y)
        pointW <- parseDouble(w)
        pointY <- parseDouble(y)
      } yield {
        new Rect(Point(pointX, pointY), Size(pointW, pointY))
      }
    }
    case arr @ _ => Failure(new Exception(s"Entry had ${arr.length} elements, expected at least 4. ${arr.mkString(",")}"))
  }
```

And you can very easily re-use the above:

```
val rects = csv.lines.map(parseRow)
```

Comment: `line.split(",").take(4)` could be better than `, tail @ _*`, also what you are going to do with `Failure` records in `rects`? Shouldn't you fail `rects` if at least one record fails?